# When text is null, text?.IndexOf(ch) != -1 is True?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

**Observation**: If text is *null*, this method returns *True*. I expected *False*.

```
return text?.IndexOf('A') != -1;
```

When I reflect the above line using ILSpy (or inspect the IL), this is the generated code:

```
return text == null || text.IndexOf('A') != -1;
```

Here is what I really need to meet my expectation:

```
return text != null && text.IndexOf('A') != -1;
```

**Question**: Does someone have a good explanation about why the Null Conditional code generated the *OR* expression?

Full Sample at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1iI1c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line above really involves two operations: a null-conditional operator method call, and a comparison.  What happens if you store the result of the first operator as an intermediate variable?

```
int? intermediate = text?.IndexOf('A');
return intermediate != -1;
```

Clearly if `text` is null then `intermediate` will also be null.  Comparing this with *any* integer value using `!=` will return `true`.

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false **except for != (not equal)**.

This code *can* be written using the null-conditional operator as long as you can use a different operator to ensure a comparison with null evaluates to `false`.  In this case,

```
return text?.IndexOf('A') > -1;
```

will return the output you expected.

Comment: Thanks for that very good analysis and especially the MSDN bit. It's a good lesson to learn about comparing nullable types. Others at my work have been bitten by it as well.